# How can I add a StorageImage to PersistentDescriptorSet?

Tags: rust, traits, vulkan

I have create a `StorageImage` and am trying to add it to a persistent descriptor set so that it can be used in a compute shader.

However when I use the `add_image` function of `PersistentDescriptorSetBuilder` to add an image like this:

```rust
PersistentDescriptorSet::start(layout.clone())
            .add_image(image.clone())
```

it throws this error:

```
the trait bound `vulkano::image::StorageImage: SafeDeref` is not satisfied
required because of the requirements on the impl of `ImageViewAbstract` for `vulkano::image::StorageImage`
required for the cast to the object type `dyn ImageViewAbstract
```

So how can I add a `StorageImage` to a `PersistentDescriptorSet`?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by first creating the PersistentDescriptorSet like in the example for a basic compute shader in vulkano repo.

Then use `ImageView::new(image.clone())` like mentioned in this issue: [vulkano-www#93](https://github.com/vulkano-rs/vulkano-www/issues/93)